# Seg fault is caused when I change how I malloc a double pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

I tried two ways to malloc double pointer, but one of them causes seg fault.
I ask this question if I can get an answer why..
(Tried to find an answer, but couldn't find a solved question on this.)

Here's my code:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 
  4 #define N 3
  5 
  6 void printDPWithEarlyInit();
  7 void printDPWithDynamicInit();
  8 
  9 int main(){
 10     printDPWithEarlyInit();
 11     printDPWithDynamicInit();
 12     return 0;
 13 }
 14 
 15 void printDPWithEarlyInit(){
 16     printf("### printDPWithEarlyInit() ###\n");
 17     int** dp = malloc(N*sizeof(int*));
 18     *(dp+0) = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
 19     *(dp+1) = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
 20     *(dp+2) = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
 21 
 22     for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
 23         for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
 24             *(*(dp+j)+i) = i*j;
 25         }
 26     }
 27 
 28     for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
 29         for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
 30             printf("%d\t", *(*(dp+j)+i));
 31         }
 32         printf("\n");
 33     }
 34 }
 35 
 36 void printDPWithDynamicInit(){
 37     printf("### printDPWithDynamicInit() ###\n");
 38 
 39     int** dp = malloc(N*sizeof(int*));
 40 
 41     for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
 42         *(dp+i) = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
 43         for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
 44             *(*(dp+j)+i) = i*j;
 45         }
 46     }
 47 
 48     for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
 49         for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
 50             printf("%d\t", *(*(dp+j)+i));
 51         }
 52         printf("\n");
 53     }
 54 }
```

When I run this program,
the first method, printDPWithEarlyInit(), works without an error.

It prints out:

0    0    0

0    1    2

0    2    4

But the second method, printDPWithDynamicInit(), returns seg fault.
It seems that I should not assign any value before malloc all the single pointers pointed by the double pointer.

But could you please explain why?

Comment: `*(*(dp+j)+i)`...really?

Comment: Jeez.... what a stupid mistake..

Comment: Do you know that `*(x+y)` is exactly the same as `x[y]`? Perhaps tha latter form is somewhat easier on the eyes, and maybe, just maybe, it would allow to spot the mistake a tiny bit faster.

Comment: @n.m. yes, I'm using that convention as well (more frequently). I used the *(x+y) convention just for this example, and maybe that confused me to make this stupid mistake..

Comment: For the sake of readability, change `*(dp+i)` to `dp[i]`, and `*(*(dp+j)+i)` to `dp[j][i]` (and of course, as mentioned in previous answers and comments here, swap those indices when you're done).

Answer (score 0):

The code mixes the indices.

This

```
 *(*(dp+j)+i) = i*j;
```

should be

```
 *(*(dp+i)+j) = i*j;
```

As both dimensions are the same this is not relevant for the 1st snippet.